# Posting to ReviewBoard from TortoiseHg Throws Error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

When I click and post it to ReviewBoard it just hangs and does nothing. How to get Tortoise to work with ReviewBoard?

Versions: Tortoisehg 2.1.2
Reviewboard: 1.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewboard from repositories was giving errors,

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/mdelagra/mercurial-reviewboard

Worked fine.